# How to finish an Acitivity by using mobile back button in android?

Tags: android

In my sample app I have two activities having name `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`. From the `SecondActivity` I want to pass some data through intent by using mobile back button and here I also want to finish the `SecondActivity`, but as I press the back button in my `SecondActivity`, it get me back to my `FirstActivity`,but it does not finish the `SecondActivity`. Please help me that how can I finish the `SecondActivity`.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
         {  
             Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
             //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

             intent.putExtra("Data1", data1);
             intent.putExtra("Data2", data2);

             startActivity(intent);
             finish();   
         }
         return true;
     }
```

Comment: I thought it is finishActivity(); and not finish();

Comment: SecondActivity.this.finish();

Comment: its `finish()` only. So OP is right here.

Comment: How are you launching 2nd Activity? I mean you are launching 2nd activity from 1st activity itself?

Comment: Why don't you override onBackPressed and send a broadcast-intent, it is not the cleanest solution, but I think it would avoid your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `startActivityForResult` in the FirstActivity, and before finishing the second one, use `setResult` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the documentation for [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) which is the correct way to do what you're doing.

But yes, in the above example, `SecondActivity.this.finish()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
// Back Button Press
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
                //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                intent.putExtra("Data1", data1);
                intent.putExtra("Data2", data2);

                startActivity(intent);
                SecondActivity.this.finish();  
                return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```